# Connect to remote server which is listening to specfic ip

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access

I have a remote linux server and the it's  ssh  is listening to a specfic ip . However the client's ip was changed and now i couldn't access this server .
I know the username ,password and the ip. 
Is their any way to access this server ?

Comment: I assume the server has a static IP, while you home IP changed and you have a firewall rule that allows only that IP to access the server?

Comment: not firewall but sshd_config

Comment: Most server hosting companies provide a console access to the server (called KVM on IP or similar). Check whether your's give such an access and log to the server from the console.

Comment: is there any other way

Comment: If your new IP is in the same network and you have a configurable router (or modem in bridge mode), you can try assigning the old IP to the router.

Comment: my isp  puts each subscriber in his own subnet :/30

Answer (score 1):

You will need console access to solve this without having access to the network. This is not a firewall related issue but rather a issue in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file which is configured to bind to the address.

If the server still has the IP address configured, and you have access to another server on the same network there is an option to configure an IP address in the same subnet on another server and try that to gain access. Take care to not create IP conflicts.

Comment: my isp puts each subscriber in his own subnet :/30

Comment: That makes it pretty hard. Are there any other services listening on the machine apart from SSH? If there is no other way into the machine, I'm afraid console access is the only remaining option. 

If this is a virtual machine, access may be provided through a customer portal or control panel depending on the hoster.

Comment: their is some servers some opened ports for http, https ,dns , ftp  services

Comment: Perhaps the FTP service has access to the sshd_config, if so you could edit it and then request a reboot. This would restart SSH with the new config and you would be able to log in. Make sure the syntax is correct before requesting a reboot or it will not work. This is quite a long shot to be honest.

Comment: i have already tried the ftp trick but i could edit or replace the sshd_config beause it requires root privileges also it tried rsync also it tried to push cronjob file but is also requires root privileges